# I have a fix length file how to extract the data to looks like csv file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, cut

So I have the following file:

```
HDR2013100120131001000000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
BDY         1         1<record><entry unit="Baneling"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Baneling"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>20</value></entry><entry unit="Baneling"><name>GAS</name><value>25</value></entry><entry unit="Baneling"><name>HP</name><value>30</value></entry><entry unit="Baneling"><name>MINERAL</name><value>75</value></entry><entry unit="Baneling"><name>POP</name><value>.50</value></entry><entry unit="Baneling"><name>SPEED</name><value>2.50</value></entry><entry unit="Baneling"><name
BDY         1         2>TYPE</name><value>-</value></entry><entry unit="Baneling"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.95</value></entry><entry unit="Brood Lord"><name>ARMOR</name><value>1</value></entry><entry unit="Brood Lord"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>34</value></entry><entry unit="Brood Lord"><name>GAS</name><value>250</value></entry><entry unit="Brood Lord"><name>HP</name><value>225</value></entry><entry unit="Brood Lord"><name>MINERAL</name><value>300</value></entry><entry unit="Brood Lord"><name>POP</name><value>
BDY         1         34.00</value></entry><entry unit="Brood Lord"><name>SPEED</name><value>1.41</value></entry><entry unit="Brood Lord"><name>TYPE</name><value>Armored / Massive</value></entry><entry unit="Brood Lord"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>1.41</value></entry><entry unit="Broodling"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Broodling"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>1</value></entry><entry unit="Broodling"><name>GAS</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Broodling"><name>HP</name><value>30</val
BDY         1         4ue></entry><entry unit="Broodling"><name>MINERAL</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Broodling"><name>POP</name><value>.00</value></entry><entry unit="Broodling"><name>SPEED</name><value>3.84</value></entry><entry unit="Broodling"><name>TYPE</name><value>Light</value></entry><entry unit="Broodling"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>3.84</value></entry><entry unit="Changeling"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Changeling"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>1</value></entry><entr
BDY         1         5y unit="Changeling"><name>GAS</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Changeling"><name>HP</name><value>5</value></entry><entry unit="Changeling"><name>MINERAL</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Changeling"><name>POP</name><value>.00</value></entry><entry unit="Changeling"><name>SPEED</name><value>2.25</value></entry><entry unit="Changeling"><name>TYPE</name><value>Light</value></entry><entry unit="Changeling"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.25</value></entry><entry unit="Corruptor"><n
BDY         1         6ame>ARMOR</name><value>2</value></entry><entry unit="Corruptor"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>40</value></entry><entry unit="Corruptor"><name>GAS</name><value>100</value></entry><entry unit="Corruptor"><name>HP</name><value>200</value></entry><entry unit="Corruptor"><name>MINERAL</name><value>150</value></entry><entry unit="Corruptor"><name>POP</name><value>2.00</value></entry><entry unit="Corruptor"><name>SPEED</name><value>2.95</value></entry><entry unit="Corruptor"><name>TYPE</name><value>Arm
BDY         1         7ored</value></entry><entry unit="Corruptor"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.95</value></entry><entry unit="Drone"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Drone"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>17</value></entry><entry unit="Drone"><name>GAS</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Drone"><name>HP</name><value>40</value></entry><entry unit="Drone"><name>MINERAL</name><value>50</value></entry><entry unit="Drone"><name>POP</name><value>1.00</value></entry><entry unit="Drone"><name>SPE
BDY         1         8ED</name><value>2.81</value></entry><entry unit="Drone"><name>TYPE</name><value>Light</value></entry><entry unit="Drone"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.81</value></entry><entry unit="Hydralisk"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Hydralisk"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>33</value></entry><entry unit="Hydralisk"><name>GAS</name><value>50</value></entry><entry unit="Hydralisk"><name>HP</name><value>80</value></entry><entry unit="Hydralisk"><name>MINERAL</name><value>100</value><
BDY         1         9/entry><entry unit="Hydralisk"><name>POP</name><value>2.00</value></entry><entry unit="Hydralisk"><name>SPEED</name><value>2.25</value></entry><entry unit="Hydralisk"><name>TYPE</name><value>Light</value></entry><entry unit="Hydralisk"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.25</value></entry><entry unit="Infested Terran"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Infested Terran"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>50</value></entry><entry unit="Infested Terran"><name>GAS</name><value>0</value></e
BDY         1        10ntry><entry unit="Infested Terran"><name>HP</name><value>50</value></entry><entry unit="Infested Terran"><name>MINERAL</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Infested Terran"><name>POP</name><value>.00</value></entry><entry unit="Infested Terran"><name>SPEED</name><value>1.50</value></entry><entry unit="Infested Terran"><name>TYPE</name><value>-</value></entry><entry unit="Infested Terran"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>1.50</value></entry><entry unit="Infestor"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</val
BDY         1        11ue></entry><entry unit="Infestor"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>50</value></entry><entry unit="Infestor"><name>GAS</name><value>150</value></entry><entry unit="Infestor"><name>HP</name><value>90</value></entry><entry unit="Infestor"><name>MINERAL</name><value>100</value></entry><entry unit="Infestor"><name>POP</name><value>2.00</value></entry><entry unit="Infestor"><name>SPEED</name><value>2.25</value></entry><entry unit="Infestor"><name>TYPE</name><value>Armored</value></entry><entry unit="Infe
BDY         1        12stor"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.25</value></entry><entry unit="Locust"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Locust"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>5</value></entry><entry unit="Locust"><name>GAS</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Locust"><name>HP</name><value>65</value></entry><entry unit="Locust"><name>MINERAL</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Locust"><name>POP</name><value>.00</value></entry><entry unit="Locust"><name>SPEED</name><value>1.88</value></entr
BDY         1        13y><entry unit="Locust"><name>TYPE</name><value>Light</value></entry><entry unit="Locust"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>1.88</value></entry><entry unit="Mutalisk"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Mutalisk"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>33</value></entry><entry unit="Mutalisk"><name>GAS</name><value>100</value></entry><entry unit="Mutalisk"><name>HP</name><value>120</value></entry><entry unit="Mutalisk"><name>MINERAL</name><value>100</value></entry><entry unit="Mutalisk"><name
BDY         1        14>POP</name><value>2.00</value></entry><entry unit="Mutalisk"><name>SPEED</name><value>3.75</value></entry><entry unit="Mutalisk"><name>TYPE</name><value>Light</value></entry><entry unit="Mutalisk"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>3.75</value></entry><entry unit="Overlord"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Overlord"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>25</value></entry><entry unit="Overlord"><name>GAS</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Overlord"><name>HP</name><value>200</value
BDY         1        15></entry><entry unit="Overlord"><name>MINERAL</name><value>100</value></entry><entry unit="Overlord"><name>POP</name><value>.00</value></entry><entry unit="Overlord"><name>SPEED</name><value>.59</value></entry><entry unit="Overlord"><name>TYPE</name><value>Armored</value></entry><entry unit="Overlord"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>1.88</value></entry><entry unit="Overseer"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Overseer"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>17</value></entry><entry unit=
BDY         1        16"Overseer"><name>GAS</name><value>50</value></entry><entry unit="Overseer"><name>HP</name><value>200</value></entry><entry unit="Overseer"><name>MINERAL</name><value>150</value></entry><entry unit="Overseer"><name>POP</name><value>.00</value></entry><entry unit="Overseer"><name>SPEED</name><value>1.88</value></entry><entry unit="Overseer"><name>TYPE</name><value>Armored</value></entry><entry unit="Overseer"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.75</value></entry><entry unit="Queen"><name>ARMOR</name><v
BDY         1        17alue>1</value></entry><entry unit="Queen"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>50</value></entry><entry unit="Queen"><name>GAS</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Queen"><name>HP</name><value>175</value></entry><entry unit="Queen"><name>MINERAL</name><value>150</value></entry><entry unit="Queen"><name>POP</name><value>2.00</value></entry><entry unit="Queen"><name>SPEED</name><value>.94</value></entry><entry unit="Queen"><name>TYPE</name><value>-</value></entry><entry unit="Queen"><name>UPG_SPEED
BDY         1        18</name><value>.94</value></entry><entry unit="Roach"><name>ARMOR</name><value>1</value></entry><entry unit="Roach"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>27</value></entry><entry unit="Roach"><name>GAS</name><value>25</value></entry><entry unit="Roach"><name>HP</name><value>145</value></entry><entry unit="Roach"><name>MINERAL</name><value>75</value></entry><entry unit="Roach"><name>POP</name><value>2.00</value></entry><entry unit="Roach"><name>SPEED</name><value>2.25</value></entry><entry unit="Roach"><n
BDY         1        19ame>TYPE</name><value>Armored</value></entry><entry unit="Roach"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>3.00</value></entry><entry unit="Spine Crawler"><name>ARMOR</name><value>2</value></entry><entry unit="Spine Crawler"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>50</value></entry><entry unit="Spine Crawler"><name>GAS</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Spine Crawler"><name>HP</name><value>300</value></entry><entry unit="Spine Crawler"><name>MINERAL</name><value>150</value></entry><entry unit="Spine Crawler"><
BDY         1        20name>POP</name><value>.00</value></entry><entry unit="Spine Crawler"><name>SPEED</name><value>1.00</value></entry><entry unit="Spine Crawler"><name>TYPE</name><value>Armored / Structure</value></entry><entry unit="Spine Crawler"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>1.00</value></entry><entry unit="Spore Crawler"><name>ARMOR</name><value>1</value></entry><entry unit="Spore Crawler"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>30</value></entry><entry unit="Spore Crawler"><name>GAS</name><value>0</value></entry><entry u
BDY         1        21nit="Spore Crawler"><name>HP</name><value>400</value></entry><entry unit="Spore Crawler"><name>MINERAL</name><value>150</value></entry><entry unit="Spore Crawler"><name>POP</name><value>.00</value></entry><entry unit="Spore Crawler"><name>SPEED</name><value>1.00</value></entry><entry unit="Spore Crawler"><name>TYPE</name><value>Armored / Structure</value></entry><entry unit="Spore Crawler"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>1.00</value></entry><entry unit="Swarm Host"><name>ARMOR</name><value>1</value
BDY         1        22></entry><entry unit="Swarm Host"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>40</value></entry><entry unit="Swarm Host"><name>GAS</name><value>100</value></entry><entry unit="Swarm Host"><name>HP</name><value>160</value></entry><entry unit="Swarm Host"><name>MINERAL</name><value>200</value></entry><entry unit="Swarm Host"><name>POP</name><value>3.00</value></entry><entry unit="Swarm Host"><name>SPEED</name><value>2.25</value></entry><entry unit="Swarm Host"><name>TYPE</name><value>Armored</value></entry><ent
BDY         1        23ry unit="Swarm Host"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.25</value></entry><entry unit="Ultralisk"><name>ARMOR</name><value>1</value></entry><entry unit="Ultralisk"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>55</value></entry><entry unit="Ultralisk"><name>GAS</name><value>200</value></entry><entry unit="Ultralisk"><name>HP</name><value>500</value></entry><entry unit="Ultralisk"><name>MINERAL</name><value>300</value></entry><entry unit="Ultralisk"><name>POP</name><value>6.00</value></entry><entry unit="Ultralisk">
BDY         1        24<name>SPEED</name><value>2.95</value></entry><entry unit="Ultralisk"><name>TYPE</name><value>Armored / Massive</value></entry><entry unit="Ultralisk"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.95</value></entry><entry unit="Viper"><name>ARMOR</name><value>1</value></entry><entry unit="Viper"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>40</value></entry><entry unit="Viper"><name>GAS</name><value>200</value></entry><entry unit="Viper"><name>HP</name><value>150</value></entry><entry unit="Viper"><name>MINERAL</name><value>1
BDY         1        2500</value></entry><entry unit="Viper"><name>POP</name><value>3.00</value></entry><entry unit="Viper"><name>SPEED</name><value>2.95</value></entry><entry unit="Viper"><name>TYPE</name><value>Armored</value></entry><entry unit="Viper"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.95</value></entry><entry unit="Zergling"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Zergling"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>24</value></entry><entry unit="Zergling"><name>GAS</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Zergli
BDY         1        26ng"><name>HP</name><value>35</value></entry><entry unit="Zergling"><name>MINERAL</name><value>25</value></entry><entry unit="Zergling"><name>POP</name><value>.50</value></entry><entry unit="Zergling"><name>SPEED</name><value>2.95</value></entry><entry unit="Zergling"><name>TYPE</name><value>Light</value></entry><entry unit="Zergling"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>4.70</value></entry></record>                                                               
BDY         2         1<record><entry unit="Archon"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Archon"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>12</value></entry><entry unit="Archon"><name>GAS</name><value>300</value></entry><entry unit="Archon"><name>HP</name><value>10</value></entry><entry unit="Archon"><name>MINERAL</name><value></value></entry><entry unit="Archon"><name>POP</name><value>4.00</value></entry><entry unit="Archon"><name>SHIELD</name><value>350</value></entry><entry unit="Archon"><name>SPEED</name><va
BDY         2         2lue>2.81</value></entry><entry unit="Archon"><name>TOTAL</name><value>360</value></entry><entry unit="Archon"><name>TYPE</name><value>Massive</value></entry><entry unit="Archon"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.81</value></entry><entry unit="Carrier (4 interc.)"><name>ARMOR</name><value>2</value></entry><entry unit="Carrier (4 interc.)"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>120</value></entry><entry unit="Carrier (4 interc.)"><name>GAS</name><value>250</value></entry><entry unit="Carrier (4 interc.)"><nam
BDY         2         3e>HP</name><value>300</value></entry><entry unit="Carrier (4 interc.)"><name>MINERAL</name><value></value></entry><entry unit="Carrier (4 interc.)"><name>POP</name><value>6.00</value></entry><entry unit="Carrier (4 interc.)"><name>SHIELD</name><value>150</value></entry><entry unit="Carrier (4 interc.)"><name>SPEED</name><value>1.88</value></entry><entry unit="Carrier (4 interc.)"><name>TOTAL</name><value>450</value></entry><entry unit="Carrier (4 interc.)"><name>TYPE</name><value>Armored / Massi
BDY         2         4ve</value></entry><entry unit="Carrier (4 interc.)"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>1.88</value></entry><entry unit="Colossus"><name>ARMOR</name><value>1</value></entry><entry unit="Colossus"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>75</value></entry><entry unit="Colossus"><name>GAS</name><value>200</value></entry><entry unit="Colossus"><name>HP</name><value>200</value></entry><entry unit="Colossus"><name>MINERAL</name><value></value></entry><entry unit="Colossus"><name>POP</name><value>6.00</value></entry><e
BDY         2         5ntry unit="Colossus"><name>SHIELD</name><value>150</value></entry><entry unit="Colossus"><name>SPEED</name><value>2.25</value></entry><entry unit="Colossus"><name>TOTAL</name><value>350</value></entry><entry unit="Colossus"><name>TYPE</name><value>Armored / Massive</value></entry><entry unit="Colossus"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.25</value></entry><entry unit="Dark Templar"><name>ARMOR</name><value>1</value></entry><entry unit="Dark Templar"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>55</value></entry><en
BDY         2         6try unit="Dark Templar"><name>GAS</name><value>125</value></entry><entry unit="Dark Templar"><name>HP</name><value>40</value></entry><entry unit="Dark Templar"><name>MINERAL</name><value></value></entry><entry unit="Dark Templar"><name>POP</name><value>2.00</value></entry><entry unit="Dark Templar"><name>SHIELD</name><value>80</value></entry><entry unit="Dark Templar"><name>SPEED</name><value>2.81</value></entry><entry unit="Dark Templar"><name>TOTAL</name><value>120</value></entry><entry unit="
BDY         2         7Dark Templar"><name>TYPE</name><value>-</value></entry><entry unit="Dark Templar"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.81</value></entry><entry unit="High Templar"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="High Templar"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>55</value></entry><entry unit="High Templar"><name>GAS</name><value>150</value></entry><entry unit="High Templar"><name>HP</name><value>40</value></entry><entry unit="High Templar"><name>MINERAL</name><value></value></entry><entry unit="High T
BDY         2         8emplar"><name>POP</name><value>2.00</value></entry><entry unit="High Templar"><name>SHIELD</name><value>40</value></entry><entry unit="High Templar"><name>SPEED</name><value>1.88</value></entry><entry unit="High Templar"><name>TOTAL</name><value>80</value></entry><entry unit="High Templar"><name>TYPE</name><value>-</value></entry><entry unit="High Templar"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>1.88</value></entry><entry unit="Immortal"><name>ARMOR</name><value>1</value></entry><entry unit="Immortal"><nam
BDY         2         9e>BUILD_TIME</name><value>50</value></entry><entry unit="Immortal"><name>GAS</name><value>100</value></entry><entry unit="Immortal"><name>HP</name><value>200</value></entry><entry unit="Immortal"><name>MINERAL</name><value></value></entry><entry unit="Immortal"><name>POP</name><value>4.00</value></entry><entry unit="Immortal"><name>SHIELD</name><value>100</value></entry><entry unit="Immortal"><name>SPEED</name><value>2.25</value></entry><entry unit="Immortal"><name>TOTAL</name><value>300</value>
BDY         2        10</entry><entry unit="Immortal"><name>TYPE</name><value>Armored</value></entry><entry unit="Immortal"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.25</value></entry><entry unit="Interceptor"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Interceptor"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>8</value></entry><entry unit="Interceptor"><name>GAS</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Interceptor"><name>HP</name><value>40</value></entry><entry unit="Interceptor"><name>MINERAL</name><value></value></entry><entry u
BDY         2        11nit="Interceptor"><name>POP</name><value>.00</value></entry><entry unit="Interceptor"><name>SHIELD</name><value>40</value></entry><entry unit="Interceptor"><name>SPEED</name><value>7.50</value></entry><entry unit="Interceptor"><name>TOTAL</name><value>80</value></entry><entry unit="Interceptor"><name>TYPE</name><value>Light</value></entry><entry unit="Interceptor"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>7.50</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership"><name>ARMOR</name><value>2</value></entry><entry unit="Moth
BDY         2        12ership"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>160</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership"><name>GAS</name><value>400</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership"><name>HP</name><value>350</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership"><name>MINERAL</name><value></value></entry><entry unit="Mothership"><name>POP</name><value>8.00</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership"><name>SHIELD</name><value>350</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership"><name>SPEED</name><value>1.41</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership"><name>TOT
BDY         2        13AL</name><value>700</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership"><name>TYPE</name><value>Massive</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>1.41</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership Core"><name>ARMOR</name><value>1</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership Core"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>30</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership Core"><name>GAS</name><value>100</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership Core"><name>HP</name><value>130</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership Co
BDY         2        14re"><name>MINERAL</name><value></value></entry><entry unit="Mothership Core"><name>POP</name><value>2.00</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership Core"><name>SHIELD</name><value>60</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership Core"><name>SPEED</name><value>1.88</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership Core"><name>TOTAL</name><value>190</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership Core"><name>TYPE</name><value>Armored</value></entry><entry unit="Mothership Core"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>1.88</value></entry><
BDY         2        15entry unit="Observer"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Observer"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>30</value></entry><entry unit="Observer"><name>GAS</name><value>75</value></entry><entry unit="Observer"><name>HP</name><value>40</value></entry><entry unit="Observer"><name>MINERAL</name><value></value></entry><entry unit="Observer"><name>POP</name><value>1.00</value></entry><entry unit="Observer"><name>SHIELD</name><value>20</value></entry><entry unit="Observer"><name>SPEED</nam
BDY         2        16e><value>1.88</value></entry><entry unit="Observer"><name>TOTAL</name><value>60</value></entry><entry unit="Observer"><name>TYPE</name><value>Light</value></entry><entry unit="Observer"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>2.81</value></entry><entry unit="Oracle"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Oracle"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>50</value></entry><entry unit="Oracle"><name>GAS</name><value>150</value></entry><entry unit="Oracle"><name>HP</name><value>100</value></entry><entry u
BDY         2        17nit="Oracle"><name>MINERAL</name><value></value></entry><entry unit="Oracle"><name>POP</name><value>3.00</value></entry><entry unit="Oracle"><name>SHIELD</name><value>60</value></entry><entry unit="Oracle"><name>SPEED</name><value>3.38</value></entry><entry unit="Oracle"><name>TOTAL</name><value>160</value></entry><entry unit="Oracle"><name>TYPE</name><value>Light</value></entry><entry unit="Oracle"><name>UPG_SPEED</name><value>3.38</value></entry><entry unit="Phoenix"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0
...
```

and more just couldn't paste the whole thing since its huge.

XML is not correct but if you follow the previous line you can see when get to 524th char the xml continuous on the next line.

File structure is:

```
Header:

Rec_type string(3) ‘HDR’;

Data_date date(‘YYYYMMDD’);

Create_timestamp date(‘YYYYMMDDHH24MMSSNNNNNN);

Filler string(492);

Newline string(1)=”\n”;

Total length: 524

Body:

Rec_type string(3) ‘BDY’

ID_XML decimal(10);

ID_SEGMENT decimal(10);

XML_DATA string(500);

Newline string(1)=”\n”

Total length: 524

Trailer:

Rec_type string(3) ‘TRL’

Num_records Decimal(9); //Note: leftpaded with leading zeros, number of body records

Num_xml_entries Decimal(9); //Note: leftpaded with leading zeros, number of xml <entry >…</entry> tags

Filler string(502);

Newline string(1)=”\n”;

Total length: 524
```

I just need the data from the body to extract it into new file that looks like that:

```
ID_XML     ID_SEGMENT    UNIT         NAME           VALUE

1          1            Baneling      SPEED          2.50

1          1            Baneling      TYPE           null
...

1          2            Baneling      UPG_SPEED      2.95
... and so on
```

Where ID_XML is the 1st number after BDY and ID_Segment is the following number. Unit/Name and Value have to be taken from the XML segment.
p.s thats just visual representation actually should be like CSV

```
1,1,Baneling,SPEED,2.50

1,1,Baneling,TYPE,null
...

1,2,Baneling,UPG_SPEED,2.95
... and so on
```

So far after extracting just the segment i used:

```
{
   sed  -e 's/></>\n</g' \
        -e 's/<value>\n<\/value>/<value>null<\/value>/g' \
        -e 's/<record>//g' \
        -e 's/<\/record>//g'
        -e 's/<entry unit="//g'\
        -e 's/">/,/g'\
        -e 's/<name>//g'\
        -e 's/<\/name>/,/g'\
        -e 's/<value>//g'\
        -e 's/<\/value>/./g'\
        -e 's/<\/entry>//g'     asd

} >aaa.txt
```

and the the output is like:

```
Baneling,
ARMOR,
0.

Baneling,
BUILD_TIME,
20.

Baneling,
GAS,
25.

Baneling,
HP,
30.
```

Planning to use awk so I use the delimiters "." for new line and "," so the file looks like csv.

Approaches that I have considered is to use

> cut -c 24-524

to take just third column where is the XML format it and return it back so I can use the numbers before but couldn't manage to do it myself.

Any ideas or solutions are welcome.

Comment: Please reduce your sample input/output to some reasonable set that we can copy/paste to test with and actually tell at a glance if it worked or not. If you find you can't be bothered to create the complete output for your given sample input that's a sure sign that your sample input is much too large for us too. Also explain where the `ID_XML` and `ID_SEGMENT` numbers are in your input as it's not 100% clear.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by `ID_Segment is the following number` - your entries are split/wrapped across multiple lines and so many have 2 such input `ID_Segment` numbers associated with them - which should appear in the output? Again, please [edit] your question to provide more concise sample input and the complete output given that input so we can better understand your needs and have something we can copy/paste to test with for a simple pass/fail result.

Answer (score 1):

With `xml2`

```
<yourfile grep '^BDY' |
  cut -b24- |
  xml2 |
  2csv record/entry @unit name value
```

Could take you some of the way.

Comment: I cannot use xml2 or xmlstarlet , since i dont have admin privileges and this is on unix based server. I am limited just to base unix commands. I could just used ultraEdit or other text-processing tool but its a practice for job task that i will have in 10/15 days.

Comment: @AtanasNedelchev, note that you generally don't need to be admin to install software, just have write access to some directory where to store it. Is `perl` or `python` installed on that machine?

Comment: No i am limited to basic unix commands. And just bash/korn shell script have to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet), this gives you the xml "ID" as the record number, but not the xml "segment" which looks to me not particularly useful (it's just a number of the chopped substring of the xml).

```bsh
awk '
  BEGIN {
    print "<records>"                    # start a root-level tag
  }
  $1 == "BDY" {printf "%s", substr($0,24)}
  END {
    printf "\n"
    print "</value></entry></record>"    # because the sample data is incomplete, close the open tags
    print "</records>"                   # close the top-level tag
  }
' file \
| xmlstarlet sel -t \
    -m //record --var n='position()' \
    -m //entry -v '$n' -o ','  -v '@unit' -o ',' -v ./name -o ',' -v ./value -n
```

This does not consider any value that might contain a comma or a literal double quote: the generated CSV *might* be invalid.

Output:

```
1,Baneling,ARMOR,0
1,Baneling,BUILD_TIME,20
1,Baneling,GAS,25
1,Baneling,HP,30
1,Baneling,MINERAL,75
1,Baneling,POP,.50
1,Baneling,SPEED,2.50
1,Baneling,TYPE,-
1,Baneling,UPG_SPEED,2.95
1,Brood Lord,ARMOR,1
1,Brood Lord,BUILD_TIME,34
1,Brood Lord,GAS,250
1,Brood Lord,HP,225
1,Brood Lord,MINERAL,300
1,Brood Lord,POP,4.00
1,Brood Lord,SPEED,1.41
1,Brood Lord,TYPE,Armored / Massive
1,Brood Lord,UPG_SPEED,1.41
1,Broodling,ARMOR,0
1,Broodling,BUILD_TIME,1
1,Broodling,GAS,0
1,Broodling,HP,30
1,Broodling,MINERAL,0
1,Broodling,POP,.00
1,Broodling,SPEED,3.84
1,Broodling,TYPE,Light
1,Broodling,UPG_SPEED,3.84
1,Changeling,ARMOR,0
1,Changeling,BUILD_TIME,1
1,Changeling,GAS,0
1,Changeling,HP,5
1,Changeling,MINERAL,0
1,Changeling,POP,.00
1,Changeling,SPEED,2.25
1,Changeling,TYPE,Light
1,Changeling,UPG_SPEED,2.25
1,Corruptor,ARMOR,2
1,Corruptor,BUILD_TIME,40
1,Corruptor,GAS,100
1,Corruptor,HP,200
1,Corruptor,MINERAL,150
1,Corruptor,POP,2.00
1,Corruptor,SPEED,2.95
1,Corruptor,TYPE,Armored
1,Corruptor,UPG_SPEED,2.95
1,Drone,ARMOR,0
1,Drone,BUILD_TIME,17
1,Drone,GAS,0
1,Drone,HP,40
1,Drone,MINERAL,50
1,Drone,POP,1.00
1,Drone,SPEED,2.81
1,Drone,TYPE,Light
1,Drone,UPG_SPEED,2.81
1,Hydralisk,ARMOR,0
1,Hydralisk,BUILD_TIME,33
1,Hydralisk,GAS,50
1,Hydralisk,HP,80
1,Hydralisk,MINERAL,100
1,Hydralisk,POP,2.00
1,Hydralisk,SPEED,2.25
1,Hydralisk,TYPE,Light
1,Hydralisk,UPG_SPEED,2.25
1,Infested Terran,ARMOR,0
1,Infested Terran,BUILD_TIME,50
1,Infested Terran,GAS,0
1,Infested Terran,HP,50
1,Infested Terran,MINERAL,0
1,Infested Terran,POP,.00
1,Infested Terran,SPEED,1.50
1,Infested Terran,TYPE,-
1,Infested Terran,UPG_SPEED,1.50
1,Infestor,ARMOR,0
1,Infestor,BUILD_TIME,50
1,Infestor,GAS,150
1,Infestor,HP,90
1,Infestor,MINERAL,100
1,Infestor,POP,2.00
1,Infestor,SPEED,2.25
1,Infestor,TYPE,Armored
1,Infestor,UPG_SPEED,2.25
1,Locust,ARMOR,0
1,Locust,BUILD_TIME,5
1,Locust,GAS,0
1,Locust,HP,65
1,Locust,MINERAL,0
1,Locust,POP,.00
1,Locust,SPEED,1.88
1,Locust,TYPE,Light
1,Locust,UPG_SPEED,1.88
1,Mutalisk,ARMOR,0
1,Mutalisk,BUILD_TIME,33
1,Mutalisk,GAS,100
1,Mutalisk,HP,120
1,Mutalisk,MINERAL,100
1,Mutalisk,POP,2.00
1,Mutalisk,SPEED,3.75
1,Mutalisk,TYPE,Light
1,Mutalisk,UPG_SPEED,3.75
1,Overlord,ARMOR,0
1,Overlord,BUILD_TIME,25
1,Overlord,GAS,0
1,Overlord,HP,200
1,Overlord,MINERAL,100
1,Overlord,POP,.00
1,Overlord,SPEED,.59
1,Overlord,TYPE,Armored
1,Overlord,UPG_SPEED,1.88
1,Overseer,ARMOR,0
1,Overseer,BUILD_TIME,17
1,Overseer,GAS,50
1,Overseer,HP,200
1,Overseer,MINERAL,150
1,Overseer,POP,.00
1,Overseer,SPEED,1.88
1,Overseer,TYPE,Armored
1,Overseer,UPG_SPEED,2.75
1,Queen,ARMOR,1
1,Queen,BUILD_TIME,50
1,Queen,GAS,0
1,Queen,HP,175
1,Queen,MINERAL,150
1,Queen,POP,2.00
1,Queen,SPEED,.94
1,Queen,TYPE,-
1,Queen,UPG_SPEED,.94
1,Roach,ARMOR,1
1,Roach,BUILD_TIME,27
1,Roach,GAS,25
1,Roach,HP,145
1,Roach,MINERAL,75
1,Roach,POP,2.00
1,Roach,SPEED,2.25
1,Roach,TYPE,Armored
1,Roach,UPG_SPEED,3.00
1,Spine Crawler,ARMOR,2
1,Spine Crawler,BUILD_TIME,50
1,Spine Crawler,GAS,0
1,Spine Crawler,HP,300
1,Spine Crawler,MINERAL,150
1,Spine Crawler,POP,.00
1,Spine Crawler,SPEED,1.00
1,Spine Crawler,TYPE,Armored / Structure
1,Spine Crawler,UPG_SPEED,1.00
1,Spore Crawler,ARMOR,1
1,Spore Crawler,BUILD_TIME,30
1,Spore Crawler,GAS,0
1,Spore Crawler,HP,400
1,Spore Crawler,MINERAL,150
1,Spore Crawler,POP,.00
1,Spore Crawler,SPEED,1.00
1,Spore Crawler,TYPE,Armored / Structure
1,Spore Crawler,UPG_SPEED,1.00
1,Swarm Host,ARMOR,1
1,Swarm Host,BUILD_TIME,40
1,Swarm Host,GAS,100
1,Swarm Host,HP,160
1,Swarm Host,MINERAL,200
1,Swarm Host,POP,3.00
1,Swarm Host,SPEED,2.25
1,Swarm Host,TYPE,Armored
1,Swarm Host,UPG_SPEED,2.25
1,Ultralisk,ARMOR,1
1,Ultralisk,BUILD_TIME,55
1,Ultralisk,GAS,200
1,Ultralisk,HP,500
1,Ultralisk,MINERAL,300
1,Ultralisk,POP,6.00
1,Ultralisk,SPEED,2.95
1,Ultralisk,TYPE,Armored / Massive
1,Ultralisk,UPG_SPEED,2.95
1,Viper,ARMOR,1
1,Viper,BUILD_TIME,40
1,Viper,GAS,200
1,Viper,HP,150
1,Viper,MINERAL,100
1,Viper,POP,3.00
1,Viper,SPEED,2.95
1,Viper,TYPE,Armored
1,Viper,UPG_SPEED,2.95
1,Zergling,ARMOR,0
1,Zergling,BUILD_TIME,24
1,Zergling,GAS,0
1,Zergling,HP,35
1,Zergling,MINERAL,25
1,Zergling,POP,.50
1,Zergling,SPEED,2.95
1,Zergling,TYPE,Light
1,Zergling,UPG_SPEED,4.70
1,Archon,ARMOR,0
1,Archon,BUILD_TIME,12
1,Archon,GAS,300
1,Archon,HP,10
1,Archon,MINERAL,
1,Archon,POP,4.00
1,Archon,SHIELD,350
1,Archon,SPEED,2.81
1,Archon,TOTAL,360
1,Archon,TYPE,Massive
1,Archon,UPG_SPEED,2.81
1,Carrier (4 interc.),ARMOR,2
1,Carrier (4 interc.),BUILD_TIME,120
1,Carrier (4 interc.),GAS,250
1,Carrier (4 interc.),HP,300
1,Carrier (4 interc.),MINERAL,
1,Carrier (4 interc.),POP,6.00
1,Carrier (4 interc.),SHIELD,150
1,Carrier (4 interc.),SPEED,1.88
1,Carrier (4 interc.),TOTAL,450
1,Carrier (4 interc.),TYPE,Armored / Massive
1,Carrier (4 interc.),UPG_SPEED,1.88
1,Colossus,ARMOR,1
1,Colossus,BUILD_TIME,75
1,Colossus,GAS,200
1,Colossus,HP,200
1,Colossus,MINERAL,
1,Colossus,POP,6.00
1,Colossus,SHIELD,150
1,Colossus,SPEED,2.25
1,Colossus,TOTAL,350
1,Colossus,TYPE,Armored / Massive
1,Colossus,UPG_SPEED,2.25
1,Dark Templar,ARMOR,1
1,Dark Templar,BUILD_TIME,55
1,Dark Templar,GAS,125
1,Dark Templar,HP,40
1,Dark Templar,MINERAL,
1,Dark Templar,POP,2.00
1,Dark Templar,SHIELD,80
1,Dark Templar,SPEED,2.81
1,Dark Templar,TOTAL,120
1,Dark Templar,TYPE,-
1,Dark Templar,UPG_SPEED,2.81
1,High Templar,ARMOR,0
1,High Templar,BUILD_TIME,55
1,High Templar,GAS,150
1,High Templar,HP,40
1,High Templar,MINERAL,
1,High Templar,POP,2.00
1,High Templar,SHIELD,40
1,High Templar,SPEED,1.88
1,High Templar,TOTAL,80
1,High Templar,TYPE,-
1,High Templar,UPG_SPEED,1.88
1,Immortal,ARMOR,1
1,Immortal,BUILD_TIME,50
1,Immortal,GAS,100
1,Immortal,HP,200
1,Immortal,MINERAL,
1,Immortal,POP,4.00
1,Immortal,SHIELD,100
1,Immortal,SPEED,2.25
1,Immortal,TOTAL,300
1,Immortal,TYPE,Armored
1,Immortal,UPG_SPEED,2.25
1,Interceptor,ARMOR,0
1,Interceptor,BUILD_TIME,8
1,Interceptor,GAS,0
1,Interceptor,HP,40
1,Interceptor,MINERAL,
1,Interceptor,POP,.00
1,Interceptor,SHIELD,40
1,Interceptor,SPEED,7.50
1,Interceptor,TOTAL,80
1,Interceptor,TYPE,Light
1,Interceptor,UPG_SPEED,7.50
1,Mothership,ARMOR,2
1,Mothership,BUILD_TIME,160
1,Mothership,GAS,400
1,Mothership,HP,350
1,Mothership,MINERAL,
1,Mothership,POP,8.00
1,Mothership,SHIELD,350
1,Mothership,SPEED,1.41
1,Mothership,TOTAL,700
1,Mothership,TYPE,Massive
1,Mothership,UPG_SPEED,1.41
1,Mothership Core,ARMOR,1
1,Mothership Core,BUILD_TIME,30
1,Mothership Core,GAS,100
1,Mothership Core,HP,130
1,Mothership Core,MINERAL,
1,Mothership Core,POP,2.00
1,Mothership Core,SHIELD,60
1,Mothership Core,SPEED,1.88
1,Mothership Core,TOTAL,190
1,Mothership Core,TYPE,Armored
1,Mothership Core,UPG_SPEED,1.88
1,Observer,ARMOR,0
1,Observer,BUILD_TIME,30
1,Observer,GAS,75
1,Observer,HP,40
1,Observer,MINERAL,
1,Observer,POP,1.00
1,Observer,SHIELD,20
1,Observer,SPEED,1.88
1,Observer,TOTAL,60
1,Observer,TYPE,Light
1,Observer,UPG_SPEED,2.81
1,Oracle,ARMOR,0
1,Oracle,BUILD_TIME,50
1,Oracle,GAS,150
1,Oracle,HP,100
1,Oracle,MINERAL,
1,Oracle,POP,3.00
1,Oracle,SHIELD,60
1,Oracle,SPEED,3.38
1,Oracle,TOTAL,160
1,Oracle,TYPE,Light
1,Oracle,UPG_SPEED,3.38
1,Phoenix,ARMOR,0

2,Baneling,ARMOR,0
2,Baneling,BUILD_TIME,20
2,Baneling,GAS,25
2,Baneling,HP,30
2,Baneling,MINERAL,75
2,Baneling,POP,.50
2,Baneling,SPEED,2.50
2,Baneling,TYPE,-
2,Baneling,UPG_SPEED,2.95
2,Brood Lord,ARMOR,1
2,Brood Lord,BUILD_TIME,34
2,Brood Lord,GAS,250
2,Brood Lord,HP,225
2,Brood Lord,MINERAL,300
2,Brood Lord,POP,4.00
2,Brood Lord,SPEED,1.41
2,Brood Lord,TYPE,Armored / Massive
2,Brood Lord,UPG_SPEED,1.41
2,Broodling,ARMOR,0
2,Broodling,BUILD_TIME,1
2,Broodling,GAS,0
2,Broodling,HP,30
2,Broodling,MINERAL,0
2,Broodling,POP,.00
2,Broodling,SPEED,3.84
2,Broodling,TYPE,Light
2,Broodling,UPG_SPEED,3.84
2,Changeling,ARMOR,0
2,Changeling,BUILD_TIME,1
2,Changeling,GAS,0
2,Changeling,HP,5
2,Changeling,MINERAL,0
2,Changeling,POP,.00
2,Changeling,SPEED,2.25
2,Changeling,TYPE,Light
2,Changeling,UPG_SPEED,2.25
2,Corruptor,ARMOR,2
2,Corruptor,BUILD_TIME,40
2,Corruptor,GAS,100
2,Corruptor,HP,200
2,Corruptor,MINERAL,150
2,Corruptor,POP,2.00
2,Corruptor,SPEED,2.95
2,Corruptor,TYPE,Armored
2,Corruptor,UPG_SPEED,2.95
2,Drone,ARMOR,0
2,Drone,BUILD_TIME,17
2,Drone,GAS,0
2,Drone,HP,40
2,Drone,MINERAL,50
2,Drone,POP,1.00
2,Drone,SPEED,2.81
2,Drone,TYPE,Light
2,Drone,UPG_SPEED,2.81
2,Hydralisk,ARMOR,0
2,Hydralisk,BUILD_TIME,33
2,Hydralisk,GAS,50
2,Hydralisk,HP,80
2,Hydralisk,MINERAL,100
2,Hydralisk,POP,2.00
2,Hydralisk,SPEED,2.25
2,Hydralisk,TYPE,Light
2,Hydralisk,UPG_SPEED,2.25
2,Infested Terran,ARMOR,0
2,Infested Terran,BUILD_TIME,50
2,Infested Terran,GAS,0
2,Infested Terran,HP,50
2,Infested Terran,MINERAL,0
2,Infested Terran,POP,.00
2,Infested Terran,SPEED,1.50
2,Infested Terran,TYPE,-
2,Infested Terran,UPG_SPEED,1.50
2,Infestor,ARMOR,0
2,Infestor,BUILD_TIME,50
2,Infestor,GAS,150
2,Infestor,HP,90
2,Infestor,MINERAL,100
2,Infestor,POP,2.00
2,Infestor,SPEED,2.25
2,Infestor,TYPE,Armored
2,Infestor,UPG_SPEED,2.25
2,Locust,ARMOR,0
2,Locust,BUILD_TIME,5
2,Locust,GAS,0
2,Locust,HP,65
2,Locust,MINERAL,0
2,Locust,POP,.00
2,Locust,SPEED,1.88
2,Locust,TYPE,Light
2,Locust,UPG_SPEED,1.88
2,Mutalisk,ARMOR,0
2,Mutalisk,BUILD_TIME,33
2,Mutalisk,GAS,100
2,Mutalisk,HP,120
2,Mutalisk,MINERAL,100
2,Mutalisk,POP,2.00
2,Mutalisk,SPEED,3.75
2,Mutalisk,TYPE,Light
2,Mutalisk,UPG_SPEED,3.75
2,Overlord,ARMOR,0
2,Overlord,BUILD_TIME,25
2,Overlord,GAS,0
2,Overlord,HP,200
2,Overlord,MINERAL,100
2,Overlord,POP,.00
2,Overlord,SPEED,.59
2,Overlord,TYPE,Armored
2,Overlord,UPG_SPEED,1.88
2,Overseer,ARMOR,0
2,Overseer,BUILD_TIME,17
2,Overseer,GAS,50
2,Overseer,HP,200
2,Overseer,MINERAL,150
2,Overseer,POP,.00
2,Overseer,SPEED,1.88
2,Overseer,TYPE,Armored
2,Overseer,UPG_SPEED,2.75
2,Queen,ARMOR,1
2,Queen,BUILD_TIME,50
2,Queen,GAS,0
2,Queen,HP,175
2,Queen,MINERAL,150
2,Queen,POP,2.00
2,Queen,SPEED,.94
2,Queen,TYPE,-
2,Queen,UPG_SPEED,.94
2,Roach,ARMOR,1
2,Roach,BUILD_TIME,27
2,Roach,GAS,25
2,Roach,HP,145
2,Roach,MINERAL,75
2,Roach,POP,2.00
2,Roach,SPEED,2.25
2,Roach,TYPE,Armored
2,Roach,UPG_SPEED,3.00
2,Spine Crawler,ARMOR,2
2,Spine Crawler,BUILD_TIME,50
2,Spine Crawler,GAS,0
2,Spine Crawler,HP,300
2,Spine Crawler,MINERAL,150
2,Spine Crawler,POP,.00
2,Spine Crawler,SPEED,1.00
2,Spine Crawler,TYPE,Armored / Structure
2,Spine Crawler,UPG_SPEED,1.00
2,Spore Crawler,ARMOR,1
2,Spore Crawler,BUILD_TIME,30
2,Spore Crawler,GAS,0
2,Spore Crawler,HP,400
2,Spore Crawler,MINERAL,150
2,Spore Crawler,POP,.00
2,Spore Crawler,SPEED,1.00
2,Spore Crawler,TYPE,Armored / Structure
2,Spore Crawler,UPG_SPEED,1.00
2,Swarm Host,ARMOR,1
2,Swarm Host,BUILD_TIME,40
2,Swarm Host,GAS,100
2,Swarm Host,HP,160
2,Swarm Host,MINERAL,200
2,Swarm Host,POP,3.00
2,Swarm Host,SPEED,2.25
2,Swarm Host,TYPE,Armored
2,Swarm Host,UPG_SPEED,2.25
2,Ultralisk,ARMOR,1
2,Ultralisk,BUILD_TIME,55
2,Ultralisk,GAS,200
2,Ultralisk,HP,500
2,Ultralisk,MINERAL,300
2,Ultralisk,POP,6.00
2,Ultralisk,SPEED,2.95
2,Ultralisk,TYPE,Armored / Massive
2,Ultralisk,UPG_SPEED,2.95
2,Viper,ARMOR,1
2,Viper,BUILD_TIME,40
2,Viper,GAS,200
2,Viper,HP,150
2,Viper,MINERAL,100
2,Viper,POP,3.00
2,Viper,SPEED,2.95
2,Viper,TYPE,Armored
2,Viper,UPG_SPEED,2.95
2,Zergling,ARMOR,0
2,Zergling,BUILD_TIME,24
2,Zergling,GAS,0
2,Zergling,HP,35
2,Zergling,MINERAL,25
2,Zergling,POP,.50
2,Zergling,SPEED,2.95
2,Zergling,TYPE,Light
2,Zergling,UPG_SPEED,4.70
2,Archon,ARMOR,0
2,Archon,BUILD_TIME,12
2,Archon,GAS,300
2,Archon,HP,10
2,Archon,MINERAL,
2,Archon,POP,4.00
2,Archon,SHIELD,350
2,Archon,SPEED,2.81
2,Archon,TOTAL,360
2,Archon,TYPE,Massive
2,Archon,UPG_SPEED,2.81
2,Carrier (4 interc.),ARMOR,2
2,Carrier (4 interc.),BUILD_TIME,120
2,Carrier (4 interc.),GAS,250
2,Carrier (4 interc.),HP,300
2,Carrier (4 interc.),MINERAL,
2,Carrier (4 interc.),POP,6.00
2,Carrier (4 interc.),SHIELD,150
2,Carrier (4 interc.),SPEED,1.88
2,Carrier (4 interc.),TOTAL,450
2,Carrier (4 interc.),TYPE,Armored / Massive
2,Carrier (4 interc.),UPG_SPEED,1.88
2,Colossus,ARMOR,1
2,Colossus,BUILD_TIME,75
2,Colossus,GAS,200
2,Colossus,HP,200
2,Colossus,MINERAL,
2,Colossus,POP,6.00
2,Colossus,SHIELD,150
2,Colossus,SPEED,2.25
2,Colossus,TOTAL,350
2,Colossus,TYPE,Armored / Massive
2,Colossus,UPG_SPEED,2.25
2,Dark Templar,ARMOR,1
2,Dark Templar,BUILD_TIME,55
2,Dark Templar,GAS,125
2,Dark Templar,HP,40
2,Dark Templar,MINERAL,
2,Dark Templar,POP,2.00
2,Dark Templar,SHIELD,80
2,Dark Templar,SPEED,2.81
2,Dark Templar,TOTAL,120
2,Dark Templar,TYPE,-
2,Dark Templar,UPG_SPEED,2.81
2,High Templar,ARMOR,0
2,High Templar,BUILD_TIME,55
2,High Templar,GAS,150
2,High Templar,HP,40
2,High Templar,MINERAL,
2,High Templar,POP,2.00
2,High Templar,SHIELD,40
2,High Templar,SPEED,1.88
2,High Templar,TOTAL,80
2,High Templar,TYPE,-
2,High Templar,UPG_SPEED,1.88
2,Immortal,ARMOR,1
2,Immortal,BUILD_TIME,50
2,Immortal,GAS,100
2,Immortal,HP,200
2,Immortal,MINERAL,
2,Immortal,POP,4.00
2,Immortal,SHIELD,100
2,Immortal,SPEED,2.25
2,Immortal,TOTAL,300
2,Immortal,TYPE,Armored
2,Immortal,UPG_SPEED,2.25
2,Interceptor,ARMOR,0
2,Interceptor,BUILD_TIME,8
2,Interceptor,GAS,0
2,Interceptor,HP,40
2,Interceptor,MINERAL,
2,Interceptor,POP,.00
2,Interceptor,SHIELD,40
2,Interceptor,SPEED,7.50
2,Interceptor,TOTAL,80
2,Interceptor,TYPE,Light
2,Interceptor,UPG_SPEED,7.50
2,Mothership,ARMOR,2
2,Mothership,BUILD_TIME,160
2,Mothership,GAS,400
2,Mothership,HP,350
2,Mothership,MINERAL,
2,Mothership,POP,8.00
2,Mothership,SHIELD,350
2,Mothership,SPEED,1.41
2,Mothership,TOTAL,700
2,Mothership,TYPE,Massive
2,Mothership,UPG_SPEED,1.41
2,Mothership Core,ARMOR,1
2,Mothership Core,BUILD_TIME,30
2,Mothership Core,GAS,100
2,Mothership Core,HP,130
2,Mothership Core,MINERAL,
2,Mothership Core,POP,2.00
2,Mothership Core,SHIELD,60
2,Mothership Core,SPEED,1.88
2,Mothership Core,TOTAL,190
2,Mothership Core,TYPE,Armored
2,Mothership Core,UPG_SPEED,1.88
2,Observer,ARMOR,0
2,Observer,BUILD_TIME,30
2,Observer,GAS,75
2,Observer,HP,40
2,Observer,MINERAL,
2,Observer,POP,1.00
2,Observer,SHIELD,20
2,Observer,SPEED,1.88
2,Observer,TOTAL,60
2,Observer,TYPE,Light
2,Observer,UPG_SPEED,2.81
2,Oracle,ARMOR,0
2,Oracle,BUILD_TIME,50
2,Oracle,GAS,150
2,Oracle,HP,100
2,Oracle,MINERAL,
2,Oracle,POP,3.00
2,Oracle,SHIELD,60
2,Oracle,SPEED,3.38
2,Oracle,TOTAL,160
2,Oracle,TYPE,Light
2,Oracle,UPG_SPEED,3.38
2,Phoenix,ARMOR,0
```

Comment: It's a fool's errand to try to parse XML with sed.

Answer (score -1):

Using any POSIX awk and assuming your data values don't contain any of the tags `<entry unit="...">`, `<name>`, `<value>`, `</name>` or `</value>` (it could be made more robust but never 100% robust and I expect this is probably good enough for your actual needs anyway):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    BEGIN { OFS="," }
    NR == 1 { next }
    $2 != id {
        if ( id != "" ) {
            prtRec()
        }
        id = $2
        rec = ""
    }
    {
        # Strip the leading irrelevant chars and join
        # all the lines in each record.
        sub(/([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){2}/,"")
        rec = rec $0
    }
    END {
        prtRec()
    }

    function prtRec(    entry, numSegs, unit) {
        # format and print the current record

        if ( !doneHdr++ ) {
            print "ID_XML", "ID_SEGMENT", "UNIT", "NAME", "VALUE"
        }

        # Strip all leading and/or trailing spaces from the record
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",rec)

        # Replace these tag ends with newline chars, which cannot be
        # present in the record, so we can negate them in the regexp
        gsub("</(name|value)>","\n",rec)

        while ( match(rec,/<entry unit="[^"]*"><name>[^\n]*\n<value>[^\n]*\n<\/entry>/) ) {
            entry = substr(rec,RSTART,RLENGTH)

            split(entry,parts,/<entry unit="|"><name>|<value>|\n/)

            print id, ++numSegs, parts[2], parts[3], parts[5]

            rec = substr(rec,RSTART+RLENGTH)
        }
    }
'  "${@:--}"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
ID_XML,ID_SEGMENT,UNIT,NAME,VALUE
1,1,Baneling,ARMOR,0
1,2,Baneling,BUILD_TIME,20
1,3,Baneling,GAS,25
1,4,Baneling,HP,30
1,5,Baneling,MINERAL,75
1,6,Baneling,POP,.50
1,7,Baneling,SPEED,2.50
1,8,Baneling,UPG_SPEED,2.95
1,9,Brood Lord,ARMOR,1
1,10,Brood Lord,BUILD_TIME,34
1,11,Brood Lord,GAS,250
1,12,Brood Lord,HP,225
1,13,Brood Lord,MINERAL,300
1,14,Brood Lord,POP,34.00
1,15,Brood Lord,SPEED,1.41
1,16,Brood Lord,TYPE,Armored / Massive
1,17,Brood Lord,UPG_SPEED,1.41
1,18,Broodling,ARMOR,0
1,19,Broodling,BUILD_TIME,1
1,20,Broodling,GAS,0
1,21,Broodling,MINERAL,0
1,22,Broodling,POP,.00
1,23,Broodling,SPEED,3.84
1,24,Broodling,TYPE,Light
1,25,Broodling,UPG_SPEED,3.84
1,26,Changeling,ARMOR,0
1,27,Changeling,BUILD_TIME,1
1,28,Changeling,HP,5
1,29,Changeling,MINERAL,0
1,30,Changeling,POP,.00
1,31,Changeling,SPEED,2.25
1,32,Changeling,TYPE,Light
1,33,Changeling,UPG_SPEED,2.25
1,34,Corruptor,BUILD_TIME,40
1,35,Corruptor,GAS,100
1,36,Corruptor,HP,200
1,37,Corruptor,MINERAL,150
1,38,Corruptor,POP,2.00
1,39,Corruptor,SPEED,2.95
1,40,Corruptor,TYPE,Arm7ored
1,41,Corruptor,UPG_SPEED,2.95
1,42,Drone,ARMOR,0
1,43,Drone,BUILD_TIME,17
1,44,Drone,GAS,0
1,45,Drone,HP,40
1,46,Drone,MINERAL,50
1,47,Drone,POP,1.00
1,48,Drone,SPE8ED,2.81
1,49,Drone,TYPE,Light
1,50,Drone,UPG_SPEED,2.81
1,51,Hydralisk,ARMOR,0
1,52,Hydralisk,BUILD_TIME,33
1,53,Hydralisk,GAS,50
1,54,Hydralisk,HP,80
1,55,Hydralisk,POP,2.00
1,56,Hydralisk,SPEED,2.25
1,57,Hydralisk,TYPE,Light
1,58,Hydralisk,UPG_SPEED,2.25
1,59,Infested Terran,ARMOR,0
1,60,Infested Terran,BUILD_TIME,50
1,61,Infested Terran,HP,50
1,62,Infested Terran,MINERAL,0
1,63,Infested Terran,POP,.00
1,64,Infested Terran,SPEED,1.50
1,65,Infested Terran,TYPE,-
1,66,Infested Terran,UPG_SPEED,1.50
1,67,Infestor,BUILD_TIME,50
1,68,Infestor,GAS,150
1,69,Infestor,HP,90
1,70,Infestor,MINERAL,100
1,71,Infestor,POP,2.00
1,72,Infestor,SPEED,2.25
1,73,Infestor,TYPE,Armored
1,74,Infe12stor,UPG_SPEED,2.25
1,75,Locust,ARMOR,0
1,76,Locust,BUILD_TIME,5
1,77,Locust,GAS,0
1,78,Locust,HP,65
1,79,Locust,MINERAL,0
1,80,Locust,POP,.00
1,81,Locust,TYPE,Light
1,82,Locust,UPG_SPEED,1.88
1,83,Mutalisk,ARMOR,0
1,84,Mutalisk,BUILD_TIME,33
1,85,Mutalisk,GAS,100
1,86,Mutalisk,HP,120
1,87,Mutalisk,MINERAL,100
1,88,Mutalisk,SPEED,3.75
1,89,Mutalisk,TYPE,Light
1,90,Mutalisk,UPG_SPEED,3.75
1,91,Overlord,ARMOR,0
1,92,Overlord,BUILD_TIME,25
1,93,Overlord,GAS,0
1,94,Overlord,MINERAL,100
1,95,Overlord,POP,.00
1,96,Overlord,SPEED,.59
1,97,Overlord,TYPE,Armored
1,98,Overlord,UPG_SPEED,1.88
1,99,Overseer,ARMOR,0
1,100,Overseer,BUILD_TIME,17
1,101,Overseer,HP,200
1,102,Overseer,MINERAL,150
1,103,Overseer,POP,.00
1,104,Overseer,SPEED,1.88
1,105,Overseer,TYPE,Armored
1,106,Overseer,UPG_SPEED,2.75
1,107,Queen,BUILD_TIME,50
1,108,Queen,GAS,0
1,109,Queen,HP,175
1,110,Queen,MINERAL,150
1,111,Queen,POP,2.00
1,112,Queen,SPEED,.94
1,113,Queen,TYPE,-
1,114,Queen,UPG_SPEED18,.94
1,115,Roach,ARMOR,1
1,116,Roach,BUILD_TIME,27
1,117,Roach,GAS,25
1,118,Roach,HP,145
1,119,Roach,MINERAL,75
1,120,Roach,POP,2.00
1,121,Roach,SPEED,2.25
1,122,Roach,UPG_SPEED,3.00
1,123,Spine Crawler,ARMOR,2
1,124,Spine Crawler,BUILD_TIME,50
1,125,Spine Crawler,GAS,0
1,126,Spine Crawler,HP,300
1,127,Spine Crawler,MINERAL,150
1,128,Spine Crawler,SPEED,1.00
1,129,Spine Crawler,TYPE,Armored / Structure
1,130,Spine Crawler,UPG_SPEED,1.00
1,131,Spore Crawler,ARMOR,1
1,132,Spore Crawler,BUILD_TIME,30
1,133,Spore Crawler,GAS,0
1,134,Spore Crawler,MINERAL,150
1,135,Spore Crawler,POP,.00
1,136,Spore Crawler,SPEED,1.00
1,137,Spore Crawler,TYPE,Armored / Structure
1,138,Spore Crawler,UPG_SPEED,1.00
1,139,Swarm Host,BUILD_TIME,40
1,140,Swarm Host,GAS,100
1,141,Swarm Host,HP,160
1,142,Swarm Host,MINERAL,200
1,143,Swarm Host,POP,3.00
1,144,Swarm Host,SPEED,2.25
1,145,Swarm Host,TYPE,Armored
1,146,Ultralisk,ARMOR,1
1,147,Ultralisk,BUILD_TIME,55
1,148,Ultralisk,GAS,200
1,149,Ultralisk,HP,500
1,150,Ultralisk,MINERAL,300
1,151,Ultralisk,POP,6.00
1,152,Ultralisk,TYPE,Armored / Massive
1,153,Ultralisk,UPG_SPEED,2.95
1,154,Viper,ARMOR,1
1,155,Viper,BUILD_TIME,40
1,156,Viper,GAS,200
1,157,Viper,HP,150
1,158,Viper,MINERAL,12500
1,159,Viper,POP,3.00
1,160,Viper,SPEED,2.95
1,161,Viper,TYPE,Armored
1,162,Viper,UPG_SPEED,2.95
1,163,Zergling,ARMOR,0
1,164,Zergling,BUILD_TIME,24
1,165,Zergling,GAS,0
1,166,Zergli26ng,HP,35
1,167,Zergling,MINERAL,25
1,168,Zergling,POP,.50
1,169,Zergling,SPEED,2.95
1,170,Zergling,TYPE,Light
1,171,Zergling,UPG_SPEED,4.70
2,1,Archon,ARMOR,0
2,2,Archon,BUILD_TIME,12
2,3,Archon,GAS,300
2,4,Archon,HP,10
2,5,Archon,MINERAL,
2,6,Archon,POP,4.00
2,7,Archon,SHIELD,350
2,8,Archon,TOTAL,360
2,9,Archon,TYPE,Massive
2,10,Archon,UPG_SPEED,2.81
2,11,Carrier (4 interc.),ARMOR,2
2,12,Carrier (4 interc.),BUILD_TIME,120
2,13,Carrier (4 interc.),GAS,250
2,14,Carrier (4 interc.),MINERAL,
2,15,Carrier (4 interc.),POP,6.00
2,16,Carrier (4 interc.),SHIELD,150
2,17,Carrier (4 interc.),SPEED,1.88
2,18,Carrier (4 interc.),TOTAL,450
2,19,Carrier (4 interc.),TYPE,Armored / Massi4ve
2,20,Carrier (4 interc.),UPG_SPEED,1.88
2,21,Colossus,ARMOR,1
2,22,Colossus,BUILD_TIME,75
2,23,Colossus,GAS,200
2,24,Colossus,HP,200
2,25,Colossus,MINERAL,
2,26,Colossus,POP,6.00
2,27,Colossus,SPEED,2.25
2,28,Colossus,TOTAL,350
2,29,Colossus,TYPE,Armored / Massive
2,30,Colossus,UPG_SPEED,2.25
2,31,Dark Templar,ARMOR,1
2,32,Dark Templar,BUILD_TIME,55
2,33,Dark Templar,HP,40
2,34,Dark Templar,MINERAL,
2,35,Dark Templar,POP,2.00
2,36,Dark Templar,SHIELD,80
2,37,Dark Templar,SPEED,2.81
2,38,Dark Templar,TOTAL,120
2,39,7Dark Templar,TYPE,-
2,40,Dark Templar,UPG_SPEED,2.81
2,41,High Templar,ARMOR,0
2,42,High Templar,BUILD_TIME,55
2,43,High Templar,GAS,150
2,44,High Templar,HP,40
2,45,High Templar,MINERAL,
2,46,High T8emplar,POP,2.00
2,47,High Templar,SHIELD,40
2,48,High Templar,SPEED,1.88
2,49,High Templar,TOTAL,80
2,50,High Templar,TYPE,-
2,51,High Templar,UPG_SPEED,1.88
2,52,Immortal,ARMOR,1
2,53,Immortal,GAS,100
2,54,Immortal,HP,200
2,55,Immortal,MINERAL,
2,56,Immortal,POP,4.00
2,57,Immortal,SHIELD,100
2,58,Immortal,SPEED,2.25
2,59,Immortal,TYPE,Armored
2,60,Immortal,UPG_SPEED,2.25
2,61,Interceptor,ARMOR,0
2,62,Interceptor,BUILD_TIME,8
2,63,Interceptor,GAS,0
2,64,Interceptor,HP,40
2,65,Interceptor,MINERAL,
2,66,Interceptor,SHIELD,40
2,67,Interceptor,SPEED,7.50
2,68,Interceptor,TOTAL,80
2,69,Interceptor,TYPE,Light
2,70,Interceptor,UPG_SPEED,7.50
2,71,Mothership,ARMOR,2
2,72,Moth12ership,BUILD_TIME,160
2,73,Mothership,GAS,400
2,74,Mothership,HP,350
2,75,Mothership,MINERAL,
2,76,Mothership,POP,8.00
2,77,Mothership,SHIELD,350
2,78,Mothership,SPEED,1.41
2,79,Mothership,TOT13AL,700
2,80,Mothership,TYPE,Massive
2,81,Mothership,UPG_SPEED,1.41
2,82,Mothership Core,ARMOR,1
2,83,Mothership Core,BUILD_TIME,30
2,84,Mothership Core,GAS,100
2,85,Mothership Core,HP,130
2,86,Mothership Co14re,MINERAL,
2,87,Mothership Core,POP,2.00
2,88,Mothership Core,SHIELD,60
2,89,Mothership Core,SPEED,1.88
2,90,Mothership Core,TOTAL,190
2,91,Mothership Core,TYPE,Armored
2,92,Mothership Core,UPG_SPEED,1.88
2,93,Observer,BUILD_TIME,30
2,94,Observer,GAS,75
2,95,Observer,HP,40
2,96,Observer,MINERAL,
2,97,Observer,POP,1.00
2,98,Observer,SHIELD,20
2,99,Observer,TOTAL,60
2,100,Observer,TYPE,Light
2,101,Observer,UPG_SPEED,2.81
2,102,Oracle,ARMOR,0
2,103,Oracle,BUILD_TIME,50
2,104,Oracle,GAS,150
2,105,Oracle,HP,100
2,106,Oracle,POP,3.00
2,107,Oracle,SHIELD,60
2,108,Oracle,SPEED,3.38
2,109,Oracle,TOTAL,160
2,110,Oracle,TYPE,Light
2,111,Oracle,UPG_SPEED,3.38
```

Comment: Its almost there , just not quite but your code give me kinda the aproach i havent look so far. The only thing that is not correct is the XML_ID and SEGMENT_ID since they have to be taken from the text itself.

```BDY         1         1<record><entry unit="Baneling"><name>ARMOR</name><value>0</value></entry><entry unit="Baneling"><name>BUILD_TIME</name><value>20</value></entry>.....
```
for instance every entry of each line should have the same XML_ID and same SEGMENT_ID

Comment: The XML_ID should be correct, no? Which line of my output is it incorrect for? Please do what I request in [my comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677946/i-have-a-fix-length-file-how-to-extract-the-data-to-looks-like-csv-file/678024?noredirect=1#comment1280631_677946) so we can help you. What you just said regarding SEGMENT_ID can't work as you just stated since you have lines that wrap in the middle of an entry and so have 2 different SEGMENT_IDs associated with them. Please provide a better example in your question that shows how to handle that.